# PDE - transformation for auxiliary equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In the introduction to PDE's I came across below equations. 
 I cannot figure out how the equations (1) and (2) were transitioned into (3) and (4). 
 
**Can anybody explain the transition steps please?**

$(1) \ \ \ F(x,y,u)=0 \\
(2) \ \ \  u=(x,y)\\$

$(3) \ \ \  0=dF=F_x dx + F_y dy + F_u du \\
(4) \ \ \ du = u_x dx + u_y dy $

Comment: Those are simply differential versions of the "chain rule".  If  F (or u) is a function of x, y, and z and x, y, and z are functions of the variable t, then $\frac{dF}{dt}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$.  In "differential form", $dF= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{dx}dx+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz$